# JFrame.pack() containing a few Graphics2D objects blocks visibility of contained objects

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have a JFrame containing a few simple shapes, Ellipse2Ds they are. I want the frame to resize to snugly fit the objects which are `(240, 240)` in dimensions

When I pack the JFrame its resized to the minimum window size, not the size of the object contained.

I should also say, that if I use `setSize(240, 240)` on the JFrame, it sets the external window size, not the size of the contained objects so the Windows UI covers half of the contained Graphics2D objects.

How can I resize the JFrame relative to the size of the contained Graphics2D objects. I see they don't have the method `setPreferredSize()` which makes this oddly complicated.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class GUIMain extends JPanel{

        private int maxwidth = 240;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(maxwidth, maxwidth);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            float i;
            float imax = 4;
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();

            for( i = imax; i > 0; i--){
                circle.width = (int)maxwidth*(i/imax);
                circle.height = (int)maxwidth*(i/imax);
                circle.x = (maxwidth/2)-(circle.width/2);
                circle.y = (maxwidth/2)-(circle.width/2);

                if((i % 2) == 0){
                    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                }else{
                    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
                }
                g2d.fill(circle);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lame...");
            frame.add(new GUIMain());
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //frame.setSize(maxwidth, maxwidth);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }

    }
```

Edit: Ok now I have revised the code as above. Except the window comes out with padding on the right at bottom of 12px. Looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uON5N.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You're probably not drawing the Ellipse2D objects directly in the JFrame but rather in the `paintComponenet(...)` method of a JPanel that the JFrame displays. You will want to override the `getPreferredSize()` of this JPanel so that it calculates and returns a Dimension that allows all of the Ellipses to be displayed.

Comment: I'll edit the top to show the rest of the code minus the shapes I'm drawing.

Comment: @Supernovah: after reviewing your posted code, my recommendations remain unchanged except that again you should override the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, not its `paint(...)` method,  unless you want to discard all the benefits of Swing graphics.

Comment: Also as you can see in the three continuously commented out lines, that should set the preffered size of the frame no? Forced to be `(240, 240)`. But it still came up with the external dimensions set to `(240, 240)` not the internal.

Comment: @Supernovah: *Again*, do not set the preferredSize of the JFrame. *Again*, override the JPanel's `getPreferredSize()`.

Comment: Okay, how? Sorry I'm only in my first hour of Java coding -_-

Comment: @Super: In the JPanel that you are doing your drawing, create a public method `getPreferredSize()` that returns a Dimension object. The Dimension object should be 240 by 240. Experiment with this and see how it goes. You will want to put the `@Override` annotation just above this method, and you will want to read a tutorial about overriding methods as well as on drawing in Swing.

Comment: Note that if you set the size of the JFrame, you're including all its decorations including its top thick bar. That's why you want to override the JPanel's getPreferredSize method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11133/discussion-between-supernovah-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)